# Can only one PHP script run at a time?

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

I have a long-running PHP script that I'm testing on my computer (running WampServer) and I've noticed that while it's running, the rest of the site will not load (the browser just shows the loading icon).

Can only one PHP script run at a time? If so, does mean if a script on my website takes 30 seconds to run, no one will be able to use the site during that time?

More information:

While the long-running script is executing, almost no CPU or memory is used.

Comment: You know, if you're going to downvote, it would be helpful to leave a comment explaining why. I searched Google and StackOverflow before asking this question.

Comment: You could share your prior research, or at least some code. Otherwise it's quite a vague and broad question, not wonderous why someone might downvote it.

Comment: @mario The question is very general. It isn't dependent on any particular code, which is why I didn't post any. My research only turned up stuff related to using `shell_exec` to execute scripts asynchronously, I wasn't able to find anything even remotely related to Jacob's answer.

Comment: @mario I disagree, code may not always be required. In this case, the information we have is enough to assist in providing an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you in your Apache/PHP conf use filesystem as the store for sessions you're limited to one script running per session.

Try opening your site in incognito mode and you should be able to browse it as normal. This because you then start another session.

Also check the number of Apache workers. If that's set to one you will only be able to run one at the time. I think the default should be higher.

Comment: That was it! I changed to storing sessions in a database (which from what I read sounds like a good idea anyway) and now I can run multiple scripts simultaneously. Thanks!

Comment: Good =) You can also checkout Memcache for session storing. It's faster than mosts databases which is good if you have a lot of traffic =)