# More than 1 PHP script request not working same time on localhost

Tags: php, apache, localhost

How to run more than 1 `php` script request same time?

When I try to run 2 different `PHP` script by separate browser's tab on `localhost`. 2nd request waiting to execute, while running first request.
After first one is finished 2nd request started to execute.

On server multiple requests in same time working fine.

I tried `xampp` and `wampp` both have same issue.

Comment: Any PHP script, or particular ones?

Comment: Do you use sessions?

Comment: @droopsnoot Any scripts

Comment: @DanielO asks about sessions because of an Apache setting, discussed in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098204/can-only-one-php-script-run-at-a-time

Comment: @DanielO yes, My scripts written on laravel

Comment: Can i increase the multiple requests with session anyone?